# Why isn't the `.deiconify` function working?

Tags: python, tkinter, operating-system

I am making an os simulation, called NutShellOs.

When I click the taskbar icon, it should rebound, just like a normal OS. However, when I click it, it works the first time, but then after that, it just rebounds.

Here is my code:

```py
def clicked_on_text_editor(event = "<Button-1>"):
                Text1.withdraw()
                #Port.coords(text_editor_logo_on_port, 55, Desktop.winfo_screenheight() + (0.1 * (0.1 * Desktop.winfo_screenheight())), 105, Desktop.winfo_screenheight())

                def clicked_again(event = "<Button-1>"):
                    #Port.coords(text_editor_logo_on_port, 55, 0, 105, (0.1 * Desktop.winfo_screenheight()))
                    Text1.deiconify()
                Port.bind("<Button-1>", clicked_again)
            Port.bind("<Button-1>", clicked_on_text_editor)
```

This is not the entire code, by the way.

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to include a complete [mcve]. Also, let us know what you've done to debug this. Are you certain that `clicked_again` is being called? Are you certain that `Text1` is what you think it is?

Comment: I added a minimal reproducible example, and I have debugged a little.@BryanOakley

Comment: "I have debugged a little" doesn't tell us anything. What have you done? Also, your minimal reproducible example isn't complete. We can't run it. We have no idea what `Text1` is, or what `Port` is, and the indentation is broken.

Comment: @BryanOakley Then check the "Entire code" link. There I give the entire code to run.

Comment: @BryanOakley Also, I added print statements to do some debugging, but it wasn't very helpful.

Comment: @yivi why edit it? I closed it, by the way, but it's pretty much useless since I wrote it a long time ago. Probably one of the first question I asked, and I didnt know anything about SO.

Comment: Found it by chance looking for something entirely different. The link was dead, hence the edit.  Age is irrelevant when editing posts, one should always try to improve them  (and May is not that long ago in any case). I replace dead links if possible, but in this case it was not possible nor appropriate. Bye!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code doesn't provide much direction, the google drive link does not work.

So basically this is just a guess, I'm guessing you want to hide/show a `Toplevel`.

For some reason appears to work:

```
import tkinter as tk

def clicked_on_text_editor(event = "<Button-1>"):
    Text1.withdraw()

    def clicked_again(event = "<Button-1>"):
        Text1.deiconify()
        Port.bind("<Button-1>", clicked_on_text_editor)

    Port.bind("<Button-1>", clicked_again)

root = tk.Tk()

Text1 = tk.Toplevel()

Port = tk.Label(root, text = "Total Guess")
Port.pack(padx = 50, pady = 20)

Port.bind("<Button-1>", clicked_on_text_editor)

root.mainloop()
```

I wouldn't do it that way, I would probably do something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

def clicked_on_text_editor(e):
    if e.widget.toggle:
        Text1.withdraw()
    else:
        Text1.deiconify()
    e.widget.toggle = not e.widget.toggle # Changes True to False, False to True.

root = tk.Tk()

Text1 = tk.Toplevel()

Port = tk.Label(root, text = "Total Guess")
Port.toggle = True # Assign a toggle attribute, can be anything not currently an attribute.
Port.pack(padx = 50, pady = 20)

Port.bind("<Button-1>", clicked_on_text_editor)

root.mainloop()
```